# How does linux know where the rootfs is?

Tags: linux-kernel, root-filesystem

I'm trying to understand how the linux kernel knows where the desired rootfs is on boot.

I read this document:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

One part of interest says:

> All 2.6 Linux kernels contain a gzipped "cpio" format archive, which is
>   extracted into rootfs when the kernel boots up ... If rootfs does not contain an init program after the embedded cpio archive is extracted into it, the kernel will fall through to the older code to locate and mount a root partition

Our kernel is 4.X, but I'm guessing this still applies? This sounds like all kernels have an embedded "cpio" rootfs.

And indeed as we read on it says:

> The 2.6 kernel build process always creates a gzipped cpio format initramfs archive and links it into the resulting kernel binary.  By default, this archive is empty ... The config option CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE ... can be used to specify a source for the initramfs archive

This raises a few more questions:

1. So if I want my rootfs to be in RAM, I need to set `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE` to point to my rootfs (in cpio format presumably).

But won't that mean my kernel and rootfs are now inseparable? What if I want to make a small tweak to the RootFS without rebuilding? What if I want my rootfs stored separate from the kernel? How do I tell the kernel the location of my rootfs?

2. Furthermore, what if I want my rootfs to be on physical storage (like eMMC, flash drive, etc.) and not in RAM?

It said earlier that:

> If rootfs does not contain an init program after the embedded cpio archive is extracted into it, the kernel will fall through to the older code to locate and mount a root partition

But... how? How does it know where to locate the rootfs? If it's on eMMC I need to tell the kernel that somehow, right?

The bootloader I am using is U-boot. I checked U-boot environment variables to see if it was somehow passing the rootfs location to the kernel as a boot arg, but it doesn't seem to be the case...

Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, the location of the rootfs is passed to the kernel via boot arg. In my case, the u-boot is passing `root=/dev/mmcblk0p4 rw` as a boot arg to the kernel. So that answers one of my questions - you can pass the location to any decompressed rootfs as a boot arg.

I'm still not clear how, given some `rootfs.tar.gz` that is seperate from the kernel how to tell the kernel to untar that into RAM and use it as the rootfs. Maybe that's not possible and I just need to use `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE`? At any rate, I'll read up on the 4.X docs.

Comment: You say that U-boot "doesn't seem to" provide the rootfs as a boot arg.  Have you confirmed by looking in `/proc/cmdline`?

Comment: The rootfs is defined in the (grub) command line and in /etc/fstab. You will have to look at the u-boot documentation to know how it works but I assume similar. Why are you looking at the 2.6 kernel documentation for a 4.x kernel?

Comment: That is the current Linux doco, Panther, last modified 2018-08-20.

Comment: @JdeBP that is the current 2.6 documentation,  are you saying you do not know where to find the 4.x documentation? https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html the rootfs boot parameter is discussed here

Comment: I am saying that the doco pointed to in the question is current.  It is what is currently to be found at HEAD by people such as the questioner when they go looking.  Also note that the question isn't asking about a `rootfs` boot parameter; not that such a parameter is actually listed on that page.

Comment: "I'm trying to understand how the linux kernel knows where the desired rootfs is on boot." The kernel knows nothing about the rootfs, the rootfs is a boot parameter in the boot loader as explained in the current 4.x kernel documentation I linked.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Actually, you are right, it *is* being passed via boot arg. I can see it in `/proc/cmdline` as `root=/dev/<emmc>`. `root` is empty in the u-boot environment variables so it must be getting set dynamically just before boot. That was helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Panther I wasn't sure how to find the relevant 4.x kernel docs as all my google queries kept pointing to the 2.6 one and it wasn't obvious to me how to switch to a more relevant doc since no part of the url indicated a kernel version... thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So if I want my rootfs to be in RAM, I need to set CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE to point to my rootfs (in cpio format presumably).

That's *one* way to do it, yes, but it is not the *only* way.

If you have a bootloader that can be configured to load the kernel and the initramfs as separate files, you don't need to use `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE` while building the kernel. It is enough to have `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD` set in kernel configuration. (Before initramfs there was an older version of the technique named `initrd`, and the old name still appears at some places.) The bootloader will load the initramfs file, and then fill in some information about its memory location and size into a data structure in a specific location of the already-loaded kernel image. The kernel has built-in routines that will use that information to find the initramfs in the system RAM and uncompress it.

Having the initramfs as a separate file will allow you to modify the initramfs file more easily, and if your bootloader can accept input from the user, perhaps specify another initramfs file to be loaded instead of the regular one at boot time. (That's very handy if you try and create a customized initramfs and get some things wrong. Been there, done that.)

For a traditional BIOS-based x86 system, you'll find information about these details in [(kernel source)/Documentation/x86/boot.txt](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/x86/boot.txt). UEFI-based systems do it a bit differently (also described in the same file), and other architectures like ARM have their own sets of details about passing information from the bootloader to the kernel.

> Furthermore, what if I want my rootfs to be on physical storage (like eMMC, flash drive, etc.) and not in RAM?

In regular non-embedded systems, the initramfs will usually only contain enough functionality to activate the essential sub-systems. In a regular PC, those would usually be the drivers for the keyboard, display and the driver for the storage controller for your root filesystem, plus any kernel modules and tools required to activate subsystems like LVM, disk encryption, and/or software RAID, if you use those features.

Once the essential sub-systems are active and the root filesystem is accessible, the initramfs will typically do a `pivot_root(8)` operation to switch from initramfs to the real root filesystem. But an embedded system, or a specialized utility like [DBAN](https://dban.org/), could package everything it needs into the initramfs and just never do the `pivot_root` operation.

Usually, the scripts and/or tools within the initramfs will get the necessary information to locate the real root filesystem from the options on the kernel command line. But you don't *have* to do that: with a customized initramfs, you could do something like switching to a different root filesystem if a specific key or mouse button is held down at a specific time in the boot sequence.

With a complex storage configuration (e.g. encrypted LVM on top of a software RAID, on a system that uses redundant multipathed SAN storage), all the information needed to activate the root filesystem might not fit onto the kernel command line, so you could include the bigger pieces into initramfs.

---

Modern distributions usually use an *initramfs generator* to build a tailored initramfs for each installed kernel. Different distributions used to have their own initramfs generators: RedHat used `mkinitrd` while Debian had `update-initramfs`. But after the introduction of `systemd` it looks like many distributions are standardizing on [`dracut`](https://dracut.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) as an initramfs generator.

A modern initramfs file can be a concatenation of multiple `.cpio` archives, and each part may or may not be compressed. A typical initramfs file on a modern x86_64 system might have an "early microcode update" file as a first component (usually just a single file in an uncompressed cpio archive, as the microcode file is typically encrypted and so not very compressible. After that comes the regular initramfs content, as a compressed `.cpio` file.

To gain a deeper understanding of your system, I would encourage you to extract an initramfs file to a temporary directory and then examine its contents. On Debian, there is an `unmkinitramfs(8)` tool that can be used to extract an initramfs file in a straightforward manner. On RedHat 7, you might need to use `/usr/lib/dracut/skipcpio <initramfs file>` to skip the microcode update file, and then pipe the resulting output to `gzcat` and onward to `cpio -i -d` to extract the initramfs contents to the current working directory. Ubuntu might use `lzcat` in place of `gzcat`.

Comment: My situation is embedded, but that's very interesting. Thanks for including x86 details, I didn't know about `pivot_root(8)`

Answer (score 9):

First of all, don't be scared by the references to "2.6" in the kernel docs. The current kernels are still members of the "2.6" line, but they went through two rounds of renumbering just for "marketing purposes" (so 2.6.40 became 3.0 and 3.20 then became 4.0). Your 4.19 kernel would normally be labelled 2.6.79.

Looks like there's some confusion going on here about the meaning of "rootfs". The "rootfs" is a special RAM-based filesystem used internally by the kernel. It's exactly the same as the "tmpfs" filesystems that are commonly mounted to places like `/run`, `/dev/shm`, or sometimes `/tmp`. (Well, unless the "tmpfs" feature is not compiled into the kernel, in which case a stripped-down "tmpfs" called "ramfs" is used instead.) These filesystems just live in the pagecache, there's no backing device at all for ramfs, while tmpfs is backed by swap if available.

The kernel thus doesn't need to worry about "finding" the "rootfs", but it needs to populate it somehow, because the whole pagecache is empty on boot. That's where the "initramfs file" comes into play. That's just a (compressed) `cpio` archive (not `tar` for reasons mentioned in the docs) that gets unpacked by the kernel into the empty "rootfs". This archive can either be directly embedded in the kernel image by setting `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE` during the build, or supplied by the bootloader (that's what the `initrd` option in GRUB does). This archive is usually created using userspace tools like `dracut` or (confusingly) `mkinitrd`.

If the cpio image is not available or doesn't contain an executable `/init`, the kernel falls back to a different method where it looks at the `root=` commandline argument, interprets it as the location of a real root filesystem, mounts it at `/` and executes `init` directly. However, this is rarely used nowadays, as it requires all the necessary storage and filesystem drivers compiled directly into the kernel. In most systems the `root=` argument is not used by the kernel but processed by the `/init` in initramfs. That `/init` (which is usually either `systemd` or a shell script) takes care of loading the required modules, mounting the real root filesystem, and switching to it.

A long time ago, a different mechanism called "initrd" was used instead of the modern "initramfs". The "initrd" ("init ramdisk") was a RAM-based block device that was initialized with a real filesystem (such as ext2), whose image was supplied just like the modern `cpio` archive. That's why many places still use the "initrd" name to refer to these early-boot things.

Comment: Interesting bit about the kernel versioning scheme, I didn't know that. I thought I was just looking at documentation for a super old kernel version